# passing a variable with get request to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

**Goal:** I am trying to populate a dropdown from a database table column... I need to pass a variable from the front-end to the PHP indicating which table to ping from, as it may change depending on user selection beforehand...

- This is where I'm trying to pass my `which` variable in to use as
  this indicator — but I am having a hard time, because I am trying to
  do so within a `$.get` request? If I could get `$which = $_GET['id'];` to report/gather what I have in my jQuery with `let which = $(frm).attr("id");` I should be good to go.
- How else could I do this, I don't think I could nor think it would be
  any good practice to try and wrap a `post` around my `get` or vica
  versa? Or chain a `post` then a `get` - I just need the PHP to access
  my jQuery `which` variable so it knows which table to query.

---

**Below is my most recent attempt:** jquery

```
$('#agent').click(function(){

  let which = $(frm).attr("id");
  console.log(which);

  $.get('dlteopt', 'id='+which, function (response) { // attempt at id
       console.log(response);

        $.each(response,function(i,obj){
          let dd_data="<option value="+obj+">"+obj+"</option>";
          $(dd_data).appendTo('#agent');

          console.log(obj);

        });  
  });
});
```

*And the PHP side:*

```
   $app->get('/dlteopt', function ($request, $response, $args) {   
             
        $which = $_GET['id'];

        var_dump($which);
    
        if ($which) {
    
            var_dump($which);

            $db = $this->db;
            $repo = new coolDBclass($db);
            $selectIt = $repo->byCol($which);
    
        }
    
    });
```

here is function `byCol` btw: *(all should be fine if I can just pass the correct table variable)*

```
public function byCol($which) {

    var_dump($which);

    if ($which == 'table_1'){
        $sql = "SELECT table_1 FROM tab.cool";
    } else if ($which == 'table_2'){
        $sql = "SELECT table_2 FROM tab.awesome";
    } else if ($which == 'table_3'){
        $sql = "SELECT table_3 FROM tab.rad"; 
    }

    // ............/
```

the relevant markup:

```
<select name='agent' id='agent'><option>Placeholder</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use the second parameter of the $.get method to pass the data, it needs to be an object.

See the examples in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

```
.get('dlteopt', {id: which }, function (response) {
```

Comment: i'll give it ago